# Using a 128GB MicroSD card with a device with 64GB maximum?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sd-card, internal-sd

Samsung's [specs](http://www.samsung.com/uk/smartphones/galaxy-s3-i9300/GT-I9300ZKDBTU/) for my Galaxy S3 say:

[image: 16/32/64GB Memory]

***128GB MicroSD cards*** probably didn't exist when this phone was made.

If I insert a `128GB MicroSD card`, will the card:

- "not function at all"

or will it:

- "work fine" but only let me use 64GB?

Comment: You are mistaking "Memory" for SD storage... My memory they mean those are options for built in storage, not SD card. SD storage I'm that device is limited to FAT32, which in phones typical means 32GB. If you format the card in a PC as FAT32 with a 3rd party utility it should work fine, you need a 3rd party tool since Windows will not format a card of that size with it's embedded utilities as FAT32.

Comment: The important part is noted in the manual: `Your device accepts memory cards with maximum capacities of 64 GB. This should mean that SDXC card are supported (alls 64GB+ card are SDXC). Therefore the chance is high that the 128GB card will work. You may have to reformat it before it becomes usable on Android.

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine and you'll have access to the entire storage space.

---

It's usually just a recommendation for a better user experience in my opinion, If I used the recommended maximum SD Card size on my device It'd be able to load all my photos, music, app data  without any serious delay, however if I put a huge SD Card in my device it could take hours to load 128gb worth of photos, Therefore it's necessary to recommended a maximum size for the best user experience.

You will need to format your SD Card to Fat32 on a PC if it's not already formatted.

A good free software for this on Windows would be

---

[Aomi Partition Assistant](https://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html)

---

Answer (score -2):

I had an 32GB SDCard that had 16GB in ext2, and 16GB in fat32 (in think it was fat32, but I don't recall exactly).

I had no trouble using it under a Samsung Galaxy Core Plus, though I only had access to the latter 16GB, so in the worst case scenario, you'll probably get away with creating an unused 64GB ext2 partition on your SD card

Comment: It just needs to be formatted as FAT32 and it will work fine.

Comment: And how does this answer the question? It's not only a different device and different SD card size, you don't even state what your device specs say towards SD card sizes. Plus, your card is partitioned. That makes so many differences it hardly can be compared with the OPs problem.